# Ubuntu tablet on Pipo m8 Pro

Tags: tablet

I recently purchased a Pipo m8 Pro (http://www.pipo.cn/En/index.php?m=Product&a=show2&type=2&id=269) and would like to know if i can install ubuntu for tab.

If i can, can you also advice how i should install it.

thanks,

Faazil

Answer (score 1):

From your link:

> CPU: **Rockchip 3188** Cortex A9,1.6GHz,Quadl-core CPU+Quad-core GPU

See: https://github.com/linuxerwang/rkflashkit

> **rkflashkit**
>
> rkflashkit is an open sourced (GPL v2) toolkit for flashing Linux kernel images (Picuntu) to rk3066/**rk3188** based devices. It's programmed with python and gtk2. The kernel program is adapted from Galland's rkflashtool_rk3066 which is in turn based on cyteen's rk3066-rkflashtool.
>
> rkflashkit talks to the devices through vpelletier's python-libusb1 which is a python wrapper of libusb. For convenience the python-libusb1 programs are included in rkflashkit. Also included is binary created for Ubuntu.

The rest is up to you. I suggest to start with the read me ;)